# Easiest way to include headers for NetBeans Code Assistance?

Tags: c++, netbeans-8

I've only just started using NetBeans for building some cpp projects.  It seemed relatively easy enough to get the code to compile by putting

```
$$(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0)
```

into the C++ Compiler's "Additional Options" in the IDE. With this in place the code builds completely without any problems, but the Code Assistance feature isn't happy. It complains that it cannot find the include file  and then of course complains about all the lines of code that derive any functions defined in that header or the chain of its dependencies.

I can fix that by putting the whole chain of includes into the C++ Compiler's "Include Directories" in the IDE, and I was able to figure that out by running the pkg-config line above:

```
/usr/include/gtk-3.0;/usr/include/atk-1.0;/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0;/usr/include/pango-1.0;/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/;/usr/include/cairo;/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include;/usr/include/harfbuzz;/usr/include/freetype2;/usr/include/pixman-1;/usr/include/libpng15;/usr/include/libdrm
```

It seems redundant having to do that because as I said, it already compiles fine.

So my question is: **Am I doing this the right way or is there an easier way to make both parts happy at once using only pkg-config? If pkg-config isn't the best solution, what is?**

I'm using NetBeans 8 and the GNU tools.

Also I'm not sure it would be wise to put all my include folders in the NetBeans global options, because I have both gtk2 and gtk3 which each have a gtk/gtk.h file.